# Почему не находит приложение, выложенное в Goggle Play Market, на смартфонах с Андроид 8.1?

Tags: android, google-play, ос

Приложение выложено давненько.
На смартфонах с ОС Андроид 5.х, 6.х, 7.х и 8.0 находит в Goggle Play Market без проблем.
Но по каким-то не понятным причинам не находит в Goggle Play Market на смартфонах с ОС Андроид 8.1 ?! ((

Будьте добры, подскажите возможные причины?

Comment: какой у вас в проекте выставлен targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion?

Comment: 22, но планирую поменять на 26 в связи с приближением 1 ноября)

Comment: увеличьте версию SDK и должно быть вам счастье))

Comment: ZigZag, все сделал, как Вы написали, но счастья нет) Попробуйте сами найти по контексту, к примеру: "my fit"! Ищется, если только добавить в контексте имя собственника: "my fit Binom". Также не ищется приложение: "Bali", только с приставкой: "Bali Binom" !?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, дело в новой политике гугла по поводу устаревших приложений. Вот [тут](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) написано, что новые приложения должны иметь `targetSdkVersion` 26+ (OS 8+) c 1.8.2018 и с 1.11.2018 все обновления должны иметь `targetSdkVersion` 26+. Согласно этой информации ваше приложение не должно от этого пострадать, но какие-то параллели просматриваются. Попробуйте обновить приложение увеличив `targetSdkVersion`

Comment: Спасибо, как раз планировали.
1.8.2018 для новых приложений, старые (уже выложенные ранее) должны с 1.11.2018 под политику попадать.